# How do CellEditors work?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor, cellrenderer

I have problems in understanding how CellEditors work in Java.

I have a JTable with a model (extends AbstractTableModel).
The JTable has its CellRenderer and CellEditor.
The CellEditor only overrides
    isCellEditable()
 (one condition added).

How do the changes I made in one Cell go to the Model?
Does the Model has to implement an CellEditorListener and react on
    stopEditing()?

I have read, that the changes would automatically be stored in the model.
Is that true? If yes, how does it work? Do I have to react on
    tableChanged()
then?

Please explain the way of the data, which have changed and at which steps I have to do something.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes are applied to the model via the [`TableModel`'s `.setValueAt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) method.  The JTable itself takes care of receiving the value returned by the CellEditor and passing it to the TableModel.

Comment: Thanks!    setValueAt() is called. That helps a lot.